# javascript: document.write + php: file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to assign value (url) in a php variable with javascript.
I need to read it from a Hyperlink in a page and use it in php function: file_get_contents

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="link"></a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var jvalue = document.getElementById('link').getAttribute('href');
</script>
<?php $url = ("<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(jvalue)</script>");

$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```

It returns :
"file_get_contents(document.write(jvalue)): failed to open stream: File o directory doesn't exist"

if I write echo $url it returns correctly: "http://www.google.com/"

How can I do to fix it?
Thank you guys

Comment: `$url` is just a string to php. PHP runs on the server, not in the browser like javascript does. It won't parse any javascript code.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how PHP and JS interact. PHP runs on the server and is completely executed *before* your JS runs at all. After all of the PHP runs, then your JS code will run in the browser. PHP runs on the server, JS runs in the browser. They don't run simultaneously in the same page. You can use AJAX to send data back and forth from the server but you can't run PHP code directly in the browser from your JS code.

Comment: `echo $url;` will output `<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(jvalue)</script>`, which has the *purely coincidental* effect of looking exactly like `http://google.com/` when viewed in a browser. If you want to test PHP output, always use the View Original Source option or inspect the network traffic directly using the browser developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Common page javascript:

```
$.get('/proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(jvalue), data => $('div:eq(0)').html(data));
```

It will request url content from php and write result html to first div(you can specify some other selector)

proxy.php

```
<?=file_get_contents($_GET['url'])
```